# JSoup not properly extracting elements by class

Tags: android, html, web-scraping, jsoup, href

I have the following element in a webpage:

```
<div id="pnNij" class="post" data-tag1="" data-tag2="">
    <a class="image-list-link" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5pmY.jpg" data-page="0">
        <img alt="" src="./Imgur_ The most awesome images on the Internet_files/H7fZCNgb.jpg">


            <div class="point-info gradient-transparent-black transition">
                <div class="relative">
                    <div class="pa-bottom">
                        <div class="arrows">
                            <div title="like" class="pointer arrow-up icon-upvote-outline" data="pnNij" type="image" data-up="4212"></div>
                            <div title="dislike" class="pointer arrow-down icon-downvote-outline" data="pnNij" type="image" data-downs="502"></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="point-info-points" title="points">
                            <span class="points-pnNij">3,710</span>
                            <span class="points-text-pnNij">points</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </a>
    <div class="hover">
                    <p>Seems like 2017 has it all...</p>


        <div class="post-info">
            album · 69,542 views
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

notice how the href is equal to https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5pmY.jpg.

However, when I use JSoup to extract elements from the page like this:

```
docImgur = Jsoup.connect("http://imgur.com/").get();
Elements links = docImgur.getElementsByClass("post");
```

The element is almost extracted properly, except the href attribute is equal to /gallery/pnNij/

Why does the href attribute not contain the full URL?

Comment: Elements links corresponds to div id="pnNij" in your code. You are missing how are you getting to the anchor and getting the href attribute. Please add those pieces of code.

Comment: Did my answer resolve the issue? If so, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check the page source, you'll find

```
<a class="image-list-link" href="/gallery/WRzti" data-page="0">
    ...
</a>
```

So the href attribute is not absolute, which results in your expected results: `/gallery/WRzti`

**Solution**

Use the [`abs:` attribute prefix](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls).

**Example**

```
Document docImgur = Jsoup.connect("http://imgur.com/").get();

Elements links = docImgur.select("a[href].image-list-link");

for (Element element : links) {
    System.out.println(element.attr("abs:href"));
}
```

**Output**

```
http://imgur.com/gallery/WRzti
http://imgur.com/gallery/tCnDJ
http://imgur.com/gallery/JIHYh
...
```